# Complex query in Mongodb using Java

Tags: arrays, mongodb-java

I am totally new in **mongodb**,but need to do some complex query in java.I have one data which is of following format

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d4887c33598835a7f5ee3"),
        "username" : "shree",
        "detail1" : "d1",
        "detail2" : "d2",
        "detail3" : "d3",
        "detail4" : [
                      {
                       "firstname":"Mary",
                       "lastname":"Smith",
                       "zipcode":"12345"
                      },
                      {
                       "firstname":"John",
                       "lastname":"Henry",
                       "zipcode":"54624"
                      },
                      {
                        "firstname":"Jacob",
                        "lastname":"Tell",
                        "zipcode":"19283"
                       },
                       {
                        "firstname":"William",
                        "lastname":"Dirk",
                        "zipcode":"15999"
                       }
                    ],

       "detail5" : "d5",

}
```

Now I want query like

1.Check "username" , if match add more in "detail4".

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d4887c33598835a7f5ee3"),
        "username" : "shree",
        "detail1" : "d1",
        "detail2" : "d2",
        "detail3" : "d3",
        "detail4" : [
                      {
                       "firstname":"Mary",
                       "lastname":"Smith",
                       "zipcode":"12345"
                      },
                      {
                       "firstname":"John",
                       "lastname":"Henry",
                       "zipcode":"54624"
                      },
                      {
                        "firstname":"Jacob",
                        "lastname":"Tell",
                        "zipcode":"19283"
                       },
                       {
                        "firstname":"William",
                        "lastname":"Dirk",
                        "zipcode":"15999"
                       },
                       {
                       "firstname":"newFname",
                       "lastname":"newLname",
                       "zipcode":"newZipcode"
                       },
                    ],

       "detail5" : "d5",

}
```

2.Check "username=shree" as well as "zipcode=54624" and should **Return**

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d4887c33598835a7f5ee3"),
        "username" : "shree",
        "detail1" : "d1",
        "detail2" : "d2",
        "detail3" : "d3",
        "detail4" : {
                       "firstname":"John",
                       "lastname":"Henry",
                       "zipcode":"54624"
                     },

       "detail5" : "d5",

}
```

3.Check "username=shree" as well as "zipcode=15999" and should **DELETE**

```
   {
      "firstname":"William",
      "lastname":"Dirk",
      "zipcode":"15999"
   }
```

and database should remain with:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d4887c33598835a7f5ee3"),
        "username" : "shree",
        "detail1" : "d1",
        "detail2" : "d2",
        "detail3" : "d3",
        "detail4" : [
                      {
                       "firstname":"Mary",
                       "lastname":"Smith",
                       "zipcode":"12345"
                      },
                      {
                       "firstname":"John",
                       "lastname":"Henry",
                       "zipcode":"54624"
                      },
                      {
                        "firstname":"Jacob",
                        "lastname":"Tell",
                        "zipcode":"19283"
                       }
                    ],

       "detail5" : "d5",

}
```

Answer with Java Code only,or just attach ***link*** which is guide for such query in **Java**

Comment: "Answer with Java Code only". That is not how this site works. We are here to help YOU get to the answer, not give you the answer ourselves, we aren't coding monkeys. What have YOU tried yet? What isn't working? What have you been able to figure out about your problem, and where (specifically) are you confused?

Comment: @AndrewG I have tried enough searching on **GOOGLE** for such think but don't got answer,so I am asking for HELP with ANSWER or send me just **LINK** where I can study it !!!